# Using induction to define Indexed family of HITs in agda

Tags: agda, beginner, cubical-agda, higher-inductive-types

I am looking to define a family of HITs parametrized by $\mathbb{N}$. I want $(-)$-glob : $\mathbb{N} \to Type$, so that $n$-glob is the n-dimensional glob. I know how to construct the n-$glob$ by induction on $n$. The problem I am running into is that I do not know how to use induction on $\mathbb{N}$ in the middle of the definition of a HIT. For example, I have the code

```
data _-glob (n : ℕ) : Type where
```

and I want to case on $n$ so that I may specify what $n:\equiv 0$ is and what $n:\equiv suc (n)$ is, given what $n$ is. But, I cannot simply write

```
data _-glob (n : ℕ) : Type where
 H : ?
```

and then case on $n$. Does anyone know how to use induction in the middle of such a definition?

EDIT: Here is my (quite literal) "black board" inductive definition of _-glob. Its pretty messy and I'm sure there are more elgant ways to define it but this is what I'm trying to turn into agda code:

```
0-glob where

 G0 : 0-glob


1-glob where

 in : 0-glob -> 1-glob

 G0_2 : 1-glob

 G1 : in(G0) = G0_2


(n+2)-glob where

 in : (n+1)-glob -> (n+2)-glob

 G(n+1)_2 : in(in(Gn)) = in(Gn_2)

 G(n+2) : in(G(n+1)) = G(n+1)_2
```

Now, I'm pretty sure this give me what I want. 1-glob is equivalent to the interval. 2-glob contains a copy of 1-glob, via the constructor "in". But, 2-glob contains and additional path parallel to the preexisting one. And it contains a two path between these 1 paths. But, to actually define this as a HIT (in one go), i would need to case on n to specify the constructors.

Comment: oh, thats a typo. I think it should read in(in(Gn)) = in(Gn_2). I intended Gn to be the filler of the n-glob. Then, to create the n+1 glob, copy the n-glob with in and add a path Gn_2 which is parallel to in(Gn). Then, add G(n+1) : in (Gn) = Gn_2. So, in(Gn) and Gn_2 should be parallel n globs living in the type of the n+1 glob, with filler G(n+1). To create the (n+2)-glob, copy again with in. So we should have ```in(Gn+1) : in(in(Gn))=in(Gn_2). Add in a parallel path G(n+1)_2 and a filler G(n+2).

Comment: @Trebor This was more complicated than I hoped. I'm probably going to end up asking my advisor about this. Thank you for the help, though!

Comment: `G(n+2) : in(G(n+1)) = G(n+1)_2` doesn't seem well-typed to me: the left-hand side is a point, the right-hand side is a path.

Comment: @Cactus the rhs is a path type. A point is just a term in a type.

Comment: The rhs is `G(n+1)_2 : in(in(Gn)) = in(Gn_2)` a path, yes. But the left-hand side is `in(G(n+1)) : (n+2)-glob`, a point. So your constructor `G(n+2)` has a type which is supposedly a path between a path and a point.

Comment: @Cactus ah, I think this is the confusion. $G(n+1)$ is not meant to be a term of type $(n+1)-glob$. Rather, I intend it to be a path as follows $G(n+1) : in(Gn) = Gn_2$. In this case, I use the shorthand of ``in(G(n+1))`` for the higher dimensional action of paths of ``in`` on ``G(n+1)``. Anyways, learned  a way to formalize this that avoids all this mess. Thank you though!

Answer (score 3):

Use

```hs
data _-glob : ℕ -> Type where
```

Now you can just do something like `H : blabla -> zero -glob`. Warning: This is called an **indexed inductive family**, and cubical Agda still has some unimplemented functionalities about this feature yet. You might want to look at the standard library (not the cubical library) on the `Fin` type to see an example.

Another way to do it is as a recursive type. You first define `zero-glob` separately. Then you define `suc-glob (n-glob : Type) : Type`. Now take

```hs
_-glob : (n : ℕ) -> Type
zero -glob = zero-glob
(suc n) -glob = suc-glob (n -glob)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you first method. How would this allow me to case on n?

Comment: @IsAdisplayName just write ordinary constructors, but now you can choose to let the resulting type be `zero -glob` or `(suc ?) -glob` now.

Comment: Hm, I don't really understand how that works. I guess I'll track down the type FIn in the standard library

Comment: @IsAdisplayName Can you write what you would suppose you `_-glob` to be? I can show you how to do it with that concrete example.

Comment: okay, I'll edit the post with that. I'm only going to be able to give _-glob informally, i.e., basically what I have on my blackboard. Thank you for the help!